# Setup of simple Spring MVC, EclipseLink, Wildfly, Maven project

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, eclipselink, wildfly-8

I would like to build a Spring MVC webapp with Maven, that uses EclipseLink as JPA provider and runs on Wildfly application server. Unfortunately I cannot make it run. I want to use the newest version of everything.

I'm getting the following error when I try to run the webapp on Wildfly 8.2 or Tomcat 8:

> 01:25:11,648 WARN 
>   [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext]
>   (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception encountered during context
>   initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>
> Error creating bean with name 'emf' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
>   nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>
> Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services -
>   2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [MovieTime]
>   failed.
>
> Internal Exception: Exception [EclipseLink-28010] (Eclipse Persistence
>   Services - 2.6.0.v20150309-bf26070):
>   org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
>   Exception Description: **PersistenceUnitInfo MovieTime has
>   transactionType JTA, but does not have a jtaDataSource defined.**

A Googled a lot, but I didn't find anything helpful. I think something is missing from the persistence.xml, or the pom.xml, but I can't figure out what.
[The whole exception is here.](http://pastebin.com/aLfKh0Cz)

[Here is the file hierarchy of my project. (I cannot share image on SO yet)](http://s10.postimg.org/kpej8h6ix/Capture.jpg)

I didn't open the entities package because I have ~30 entities generated from database tables.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>MovieTimeProject</groupId>
  <artifactId>MovieTimeProject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>MovieTimeProject Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
            <name>OSS Sonatype Staging</name>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss Repository</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- JUnit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JBoss sever -->


    <!-- MySQL & JPA & EclipseLink -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> --> <!-- since running inside a Java EE container -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> --> <!-- Running inside a Java EE container -->
    <!-- <scope>compile</scope> -->
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet & jstl -->
    <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2-b01</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <finalName>MovieTimeProject</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Here is the persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MovieTime" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/movietime2"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>MovieTime!</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <!-- 
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
     -->
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <!-- <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> -->
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- 
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  -->

  <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
  <!-- 
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
    -->

</web-app>
```

spring-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Use @Component annotations for bean definitions -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.movietime.controller" />

    <!-- Use @Controller annotations for MVC controller definitions -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"/>


    <!-- Add JPA support -->
     <bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
           <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
         </property>
     </bean>

     <!-- Add Transaction support -->
    <bean id="myTxManager"
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
          <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTxManager" />

    <!-- View resolver -->
    <bean class=
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/"/>
    </bean>



    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/pages directory -->
    <!-- 
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>     
    </bean>
     -->

    <!-- Configure to plugin JSON as request and response in method handler -->
    <!-- 
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
        <property name="messageConverters">
            <list>
                <ref bean="jsonMessageConverter"/>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
      -->

    <!-- Configure bean to convert JSON to POJO and vice versa -->
    <!-- 
    <bean id="jsonMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
     -->

</beans>
```

HelloController.java:

```
package com.movietime.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.movietime.entities.Movie;
import com.movietime.dataAccessLayer.MovieService;;

/**
 * @author Attila
 * 
 * Presentation layer (MVC) / Controller
 */
@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @Resource
    MovieService service;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public ModelAndView welcomePage() {

        List<Movie> result = service.findByTitle("The eternal sunshine of");
        System.out.println(result.get(0));

        return new ModelAndView("index.jsp");
    }
}
```

MovieService.java:

```
package com.movietime.dataAccessLayer;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.movietime.dao.MovieRepository;
import com.movietime.entities.Movie;

@Service
public class MovieService {

    @Resource
    private MovieRepository movieRepository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<Movie> findByTitle(String title) {

        List<Movie> result = movieRepository.findMoviesByTitle(title); 
        return result;
    }
}
```

MovieRepository.java:

```
package com.movietime.dao;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.movietime.entities.Movie;

@Repository
@Scope(value="singleton")
public class MovieRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    public void register(Movie mov) {
        // Save employee
        this.em.persist(mov);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Movie> findMoviesByTitle(String title) {

        String queryString = "SELECT m FROM Movie m WHERE m.title LIKE '" + title + "%'";
        Query query = em.createQuery(queryString, Movie.class);

        return query.getResultList();
    }

}
```

Comment: As mentioned in the exception, you need to provide a <jta-data-source> element within <persistence-unit> in persistence.xml file, with the name of the data source configured in the application server. You may refer to the Java EE tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro003.htm

Comment: Alternatively, you may switch transaction-type to RESOURCE_LOCAL and provide the connection to the database within persistence.xml as is already implemented in your file.

Comment: Currently I don't have enough time to develop this application. As soon as I can continue, I will post an aswer. Thank you Petros!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I solved this error by changing the transaction type to RESOURCE_LOCAL.